# How to disable Shift Ctrl?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I would like to disable `Shift Ctrl` without disabling other shorcuts like `Shift Ctrl A`, or `Ctrl A`, or `Shift A`.

I have tried multiple combinaison of `^+:: return` with and without :

```
- Up : ^+ Up:: return
- ~ : ~^+ Up:: return
- & : ~^ & ~+ Up:: return
```

Nothing work. Even when I start my script as admin it doesn work.

I want to rename Shift Ctrl because I have two keyboard languages and pressing `Shift Ctrl` change it. I already have the shorcut `Windows Space` so I don't need `Shift Ctrl`.

I have tried with `ahk` but I am open to any other way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"^" is the modifier symbol for the Control key and "+" for the Shift key.

Modifier symbols are used only in key-combinations for modifying other keys.

Try also

```
+Ctrl Up:: return
```

or

```
Shift & Ctrl Up:: return
```

**EDIT:**

You can change or remove the combination  that changes the keyboard language on Control panel --> Language, as shown in the comments below.

Comment: Thanks for the tips about the modifier symbols... But  I tried both of your solution and `Ctrl Shift` still continues to switch keyboard. (I also tried without the Up, and every try I run the script as Admin)

Comment: On my system it's the Alt+Shift combination that changes the keyboard language and this works: `!Shift Up:: return`. You can change the combination on: Control panel --> Language --> Advanced settings --> Switching input methods_Change language bar hot keys -->Text Services and Input Languages_Hot keys for input languages_Between input language

Comment: Thanks so much @user3419297! I could remove set "not assigned" to switch input language and switch keyboard language. Windows+space still works so that's perfect! Please add this as an answer, so I could select it!